# force a re-measure

Tags: apache-flex

I have a function that is made up of two main parts (I'll call them A and B). Part B needs to run when part A is fully done with its layout changes. However, there is no "part A is done" signal, and thus I've been calling a validateNow() before part B runs. This works but seems awfully inefficient - was wondering if there are any other tricks to force an immediate measure or something along those lines or if I'm stuck.
thank you!

Comment: -1 from me.  You provided no code and no description of what A and B are.  If they are really parts of a single function, then they should run synchronously w/o needing to do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke part B from within `updateDisplayList()`.

For that you need to introduce some flag:

```
private var partAPerformed:Boolean;
```

Then within function after finishing part A:

```
partAPerformed = true;
invalidateDisplayList();
```

And then:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    if (partAPerformed)
    {
        // Part B
        partAPerformed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally feel that adding an updateComplete handler would be a better option than adding something to updateDisplayList().  updateDisplayList() will not necessarily run during every render event.  But, it depends a lot on how things are implemented and w/ no code from the original poster, it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Some code would be helpful because I'm having difficulty picturing the situation you are describing. I mean, I'm guessing the operations going on are asynchronous, because obviously anything synchronous would make timing a non-issue. What exactly is part A doing?

In the meantime however you should always think of asynchronous operations in terms of events and event listeners. So have two functions with one listening for an event dispatched by operations in the other, rather than trying to make one function that handles everything.

Comment: +1 I was wondering if both PartA and PartB where UIComponents.